# how can i make one Slivers AppBar With diffrent behavior and desgin , like WhatsApp desgin?

Tags: flutter, whatsapp, android-nestedscrollview, sliverappbar, customscrollview

i started my project to make WhatsApp clone to learn
now i have chalange to my AppBar ( animated , scrollbe , design )

i have used
DefaultTabController
with : Scaffold
with : NestedScrollView
with : SliversAppBar
with : TapBar

and TapBar
and in body TapBarView  with 4 page

first page is non Scrolling (i did it ) ,not scroll and not animated Appbar ( cant handel , , i can handel for all Tap but i need to only this page )

second ,third and forth page is 3 diffrent type of list conected with Taps
so i used NestedScrollView  with CustomScrollView   ,,
But i cant Handel the change in AppPar PopUPMenuButtom in Actions (cant handel)

and i cant handel the first page  behavior of AppBar ,, its allows about AppBar

so i asked , maybe found any solution for this AppBar

Comment: I think, you are looking for something like https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-add-sliverappbar-to-your-flutter-app/

Comment: thanks , it help me alot to undertanding about SliverPersistentHeader ,

but it do not help me alot with designing diffrent AppBar for each tap with diffrent popUpMenu 

i think now i should not use NestedScrollView 

may be  NestedScrollViewViewPort , NestedScrollViewStatus , NestedScrollViewHeaderSliversBuilder 

but i still cant figher it